# No ServletContext set when initiating resourceHandlerMapping bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am getting this error on startup of a Spring Boot 1.5.14 application:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.company.client.api.SomeApplication.main(SomeApplication.java:34)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer$MvcCorsFilter.getMvcCorsFilter(CorsConfigurer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer$MvcCorsFilter.access$000(CorsConfigurer.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer.getCorsFilter(CorsConfigurer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer.configure(CorsConfigurer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer.configure(CorsConfigurer.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:384)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:291)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7be4b243.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$2()
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7be4b243$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f8ea674.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7be4b243.springSecurityFilterChain()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:289)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.initHandlerMappings(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.afterPropertiesSet(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:448)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2be12759.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$43()
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2be12759$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8c7cfb1a.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2be12759.resourceHandlerMapping()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 73 more
```

Here's the (what I thinK) related configuration of the application:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .and().requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(authorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), CredentialsExpiredAuthorizationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CredentialsExpiredAuthorizationFilter authorizationFilter(){
        return new CredentialsExpiredAuthorizationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter(){
        return new ClientAuthenticationFilter(clientDao);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, IpWebAuthenticationDetails> authenticationDetailsSource() {
        return new IpAuthenticationDetailsSource();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        final AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver resolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        return new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    }      
}
```

apart from the above `@Configuration` classes, I have a couple of -quite irrelevant- configuration classes. I don't have `@EnableWebMvc` anywhere, though extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` seems to automatically bring it in. If I exclude `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` with

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
```

on my `@SpringBootApplication`, the error becomes:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available: A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available: A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer$MvcCorsFilter.getMvcCorsFilter(CorsConfigurer.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer$MvcCorsFilter.access$000(CorsConfigurer.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer.getCorsFilter(CorsConfigurer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer.configure(CorsConfigurer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer.configure(CorsConfigurer.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:384)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:291)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$874e9fa2.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$2()
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$874e9fa2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$43c70e19.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$874e9fa2.springSecurityFilterChain()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

and adding `@EnableWebMvc` to a `@Configuration` class doesn't seem to help. There are some references on SO an github to the same exception, thought they did not help:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1392 (Tried, both not extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and even not defining `MessageSource` bean didn't help)
- [Spring 5 - No ServletContext set exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822278/spring-5-no-servletcontext-set-exception) (I am not creating a MVC related bean)
- [ugrade spring boot 2.0.0.RC2 exception No ServletContext set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971937/ugrade-spring-boot-2-0-0-rc2-exception-no-servletcontext-set) (Same as first)
- [Spring Boot with AclPermissionEvaluator resulting in IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367588/spring-boot-with-aclpermissionevaluator-resulting-in-illegalstateexception-no-s) (Splitting `MethodConfiguration` into it's own class didn't help)

  - And there are a couple of more questions that are not remotely related to our issue or doesn't have an answer.

Happy to provide further related details, just need guidance on what to provide. How do I get rid of the exception?

Comment: Can you post a proof-of-concept minimal project on a public source repository (like Github)?

Comment: you dont have enough here for us to help. Spring Boot is highly highly dependant on annotations used, dependencies in the project, and the configurations in play. You are only showing us a very limited view of your security chain, which makes it hard to see what modules youve turned on or configured. My suspicion is that you've not only 'not turned on', but have explicitly excluded MVC and yet are trying to use MVC classes which are not loaded in the context you're using for the security chain

Comment: @Stephan, you are wrong. Actually, that was my initial thought as well. I couldn't have posted all of my config as it would be a very long question, and if you noticed, that's why I specifically asked for guidance on what to provide further. But my assumption was wrong and a simple check of dependencies showed me that I had circular dependency problem, which resolved Mvc configuration to be postponed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turned out to be a (somewhat circular) dependency problem. I was creating a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class that has `@PostConstruct` method, that's required by `Mvc` configuration. This was actually delaying the creation of `Mvc` related configuration and context. Since there's no other `@Configration` classes left, Spring starts to configure security, which requires `Mvc` context, which in return, threw this exception.

Comment: In my case I was creating a `MessageSource` bean on a Spring Security configuration. I moved it to another configuration class and that fixed it.

Comment: In my case, a @Value in the same class that provided the customizer caused the same issue

Comment: In my case it was because I was creating the PasswordEncoder bean in the same class as the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Moving it to another configuration class and injecting it later on worked for me.

Comment: how do you find what is the real source since the answer and comments seems to be in different places ?

Comment: With this in application.properties:
`logging.level.org.springframework.beans.factory = DEBUG`

Comment: this, +1. TBH this error is a sign you have the bean dependency graph broken in some subtle-yet-hard-to-spot way.

Comment: BTW, in my case it was a custom `SecurityExpressionHandler` implementation declared as a `@Component`, which had `PermissionEvaluator` bean autowired and was autoloaded from a different module. As in Hasan's case, the security->MVC dependency was the source of the problem - the security context required servlet to exist to load, but the servlet wanted to have the beans loaded first. At first, `@Lazy` on the `PermissionEvaluator` did work, but then after another trivial refactoring which changed the load order again - it started failing again. tl;dr verify all your beans, direct and indirect.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when trying to enable H2 console. My initial Spring Security config was:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
```

After removing the 2 I didn't need, the app started normally:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true
)
```

Comment: Great catch! As I was following this tutorial (https://www.toptal.com/spring/spring-security-tutorial) to add Spring Security and JWTs to my application I was getting this error so I had to remove secureEnabled and jsr250Enabled

Answer (score 0):

[Change `WebApplicationInitializer` to load all configuration from the root context](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20848):

> ```
> @Override
>  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
>     return new Class[] {AppConfig.class, SpringMVCRestConfig.class};
> }
> @Override
> protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
>     return null;
> }
> ```

Comment: This didn't help, I'm afraid, I had a fairly complex `@Configuration` and somewhat circular dependency, when I resolved it, the exception went away.